Stepping down as moderator
I haven't been very active recently, and each time the SE staff inquired, I thought I'd get more involved again.
Truth is, it's not going to happen anytime soon - other commitments, life going on, etc.
Since it's not fair to bricks.se to stay moderator while being for the most part inactive, I'm finally accepting that it's better that I step down so that someone else can get the opportunity. I know there are a lot of good users here which would make tremendous mods. Not sure how the SE staff is going to go forward though.
Anyway, thanks to all, it's been a very interesting ride. I'll most certainly try to connect again from time to time and answer questions if I can :-)

Hey Joubarc, thanks for all your help over the last few years - really been appreciated - I hope we still get to benefit from your wisdom in the future - don't forget that at your rep level you'll effectively still be a mod here ;)

We appreciate the time you've put into the site, hopefully we will still see you around.
